# How to integrate or convert Python script to be used in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, python, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a chrome extension which generates a meme, given a selected text. The intended functionality is to select some string of text, open a context menu, and click the "Generate Meme" button which will either download the generated meme or provide a link to the image.

My dilemma is that I created the meme generator script using Python's Imaging Library (PIL), however, I do not know how to implement the script into my Chrome Extensions (Javascript).

Here is the Python script:

```
import PIL
from convert import convert
from PIL import ImageFont
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw

topString = input("Enter Top Message: ")
bottomString = input("Enter Top Message: ")
topString = convert(topString)
bottomString = convert(bottomString)
print(topString + " " + bottomString)

img = Image.open("base.jpg")
font = ImageFont.truetype("Krabby Patty.ttf", fontSize)
imageSize = img.size
fontSize = int(imageSize[1] / 5)

topTextSize = font.getsize(topString)
bottomTextSize = font.getsize(bottomString)

while topTextSize[0] > imageSize[0] - 20 or bottomTextSize[0] > imageSize[0] - 20:
    fontSize = fontSize - 1
    font = ImageFont.truetype("Krabby Patty.ttf", fontSize)
    topTextSize = font.getsize(topString)
    bottomTextSize = font.getsize(bottomString)

topTextPosition = ((imageSize[0] / 2) - (topTextSize[0] / 2), 0)
bottomTextPosition = ((imageSize[0] / 2) - (bottomTextSize[0] / 2), imageSize[1] - bottomTextSize[1])
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

#Outline text
outlineRange = int(fontSize / 15)
for x in range(-outlineRange, outlineRange + 1):
    for y in range(-outlineRange, outlineRange + 1):
        draw.text(
            (topTextPosition[0] + x, topTextPosition[1] + y), topString, (0, 0, 0), font=font)
        draw.text(
            (bottomTextPosition[0] + x, bottomTextPosition[1] + y), bottomString, (0, 0, 0), font=font)

draw.text(topTextPosition, topString, (255, 255, 255), font=font)
draw.text(bottomTextPosition, bottomString, (255, 255, 255), font=font)

img.save("meme.png")
```

And here is the Javascript for the chrome extension:

```
var genMSM = function(info) {
    message = convert(info.selectionText)

}
chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: "Generate Meme",
    contexts: ["selection"],
    onclick: genMSM
});

function convert(message) {
    output = ""
    for(var i = 0; i < message.length; i++){
        output += i % 2 == 0 ? message.charAt(i).toLowerCase():message.charAt(i).toUpperCase();
    }
    return output
}
```

Any help or suggestions on how to implement this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You could host a website in python and make requests to it from javascript. I usually do this in Flask

Comment: That sounds like a good idea. I have minimal experience with Flask - do you have any tips/tutorials on going about doing this? Thank you!

Comment: Check this out: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/